Смотрю 3-х часовую вёрстку сайта и остановился на моменте где автор задаёт кастомное разрешение экрану
он прописывает в: tailwind.config.js > theme > screens такие значения: >
screens: {lg: { max: "1999.99px" },md: { max: "991.99px" },sm: { max: "767.99px" },xs: { max: "497.99px" },},

а после возвращается в html > header (в котором вложены все элементы сайта) > и прописывает там это; <header class="mx-auto flex max-w-[1336px] justify-between pt-[35px] lg:px-5> (именно lg:px-5 у меня не работает, хотя у него в видео всё хорошо)

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

что именно не работает? как ты проверял?

должно работать. если конечно, ничего не пропустили. попробуйте сделать пример из официальной доки. также авторы видео обычно выкладывают исходники, скачайте их и запустите у себя.

Я писал всё как показывает автор в видео.

РЕБЯТА Я ВЫЯСНИЛ В ЧЁМ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!!!
Просто замените в файле tailwind.config.js строчку content: на >
content: ["./src/**/*"],
